# Partizipialkonstruktion

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending, particle

Gegeben sei der folgende Satz, welcher als eine Partizipialkonstruktion umgeformt werden soll.

> Die Redewendung, die im Alltag am häufigsten verwendet wird, ist grammatisch nicht korrekt.

Ich habe die grundlegende Regel für diese Transformation vergessen. Deshalb bin ich mir nicht sicher, welche folgender Sätze korrekt ist.

1. Die im Alltag am häufigsten verwend**ende** Redewendung ist grammatisch nicht korrekt.
2. Die im Alltag am häufigsten verwend**ete** Redewendung ist grammatisch nicht korrekt.

Danke im Voraus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rein formal sind beide Varianten korrekt.

Allerdings wird hier das Partizip Passiv (*verwendet*, Partizip II) benötigt.

Das Partizip Aktiv (*verwendend*, Partizip I) macht keinen Sinn, denn eine Redewendung verwendet nicht, sie wird verwendet. Daher ergibt nur Variante 2 einen sinnvollen Satz.

Comment: Das verstehe ich nicht - Irgendwie widersprechen sich Anfang und Ende deiner Antwort.

Comment: Es ist ein Unterschied, ob ein Satz rein syntaktisch korrekt ist oder ob er auch Sinn ergibt.

Comment: @RHa Vielen Dank für die ausführliche Antwort.